# Insert foreign key in Symfony2 in OneToMany relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a problem with adding data to the db. I have two entities `InternalDocument` and `InternalDocumentProduct` in OneToMany relation. 
In `InternalDocument`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InternalDocumentProduct", mappedBy="document", cascade={"all"})
 **/
protected $products;
```

In `InternalDocumentProduct`

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InternalDocument", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * */
protected $document;
```

When I create new `InternalDocument` I need to insert `InternalDocumentProduct` too. But When i call `persist()` method, `InternalDocumentProduct` is saved without `document_id` field. It's null. This is my `createForm()` method in `InternalDocumentController`:

```
    /**
 * Creates a new InternalDocument entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new InternalDocument();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        foreach($entity->getProducts() as $p) {
            $em->persist($p);
        }
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_warehouse_documents'));
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeWarehouseBundle:InternalDocument:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
I resolve this problem. I modified createAction method:

```
/**
 * Creates a new InternalDocument entity.
 *
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new InternalDocument();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        foreach($entity->getProducts() as $p) {
            $p->setDocument($entity);
        }
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_warehouse_documents'));
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeWarehouseBundle:InternalDocument:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: There's something that I missed from your question. First of all: why are you fetching again `products` from `InternalDocument`? Second, when you persist your entity, `products` are already there?

Comment: Oh, I don't know, I removed foreach loop but still the same. yes, products already there are.

Comment: Could you, just for a test, print somewhere result of `count($entity->getProducts())` please?

Comment: I added 3 products to a document and `count` method return to me value 3.

Comment: So, it is very stange ... I can't , right now, have any idea ...